# C# - How to call an exe added into project solution

Tags: c#, executable

So I added an EXE to my project's solution. The EXE does some stuff and outputs data via stdout. I want to capture the output, but more importantly how do I execute that EXE within my program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "myExec.exe";
p.Start();
```

Comment: although the relative file path will only work if the Current Working Directory hasn't changed...

Comment: How to pass parameters into that and how to call it asynchronously?

Answer (score 3):

[`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx). To capture stdout you need to redirect it via `ProcessStartInfo` - there is an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx). Make sure also that the exe is marked to be copied to the output directory (bin/release etc).

If you need to read from both stdout and stderr it gets tricky (with a naïve implementation there is a risk of deadlock due to buffering etc)... [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258339/pconsolestartinforedirectstandardoutput-and-pconsoleexited-event-c#258387) an example using worker threads.